# Is it permissible to exclusively wear tephilin according to Rabenu Tam?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, rashi, machlokes, rabbeinu-tam

If one looks into the sources - as well as the give and take throughout the recorded history of the *mahloqeth* - it becomes clear that the majority of the world wore *tephilin* according to the *shitta* of *Rabenu Tam* exclusively until rather recent history. (cf. [*`Arokh HaShulhan, Hilkhoth Tephilin* 34](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%93):1-9)

My question is: "Can one today wear RT *tephilin* and be *yosse y'dhe hova* (fulfill his obligation)? Why or why not?"

Comment: When did the Machlokes start and when did it end?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking if a posek can choose to paskin like RT? Why would anyone think he couldn't?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Well, I guess my assumptions are that A) since Rash"i is "in" at this time, and since that designation would make RT tephilin "pasul," it would follow that one would not be able to, and B) that since "everyone knows" that Rash"i tephilin are "correct" halakhically then a poseq would be "unable" to posken like RT - at least l'ma`aseh. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist I don't really follow why those would be true.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Have you asked the average Jew, yeshiva bahur, Rav, et al. lately? The emphatic assertion - and some would say "battle cry" - would be "Shulhan Arukh!" And to even ask this question would be to betray one's stupidity and ignorance of the "obvious halakha." Just speaking from experience. Kol tuv.

Comment: RT full shittah(klaf laying down) is not RT of today,which one are you referring to

Comment: I said posek, not the average Jew, yeshiva bahur, or Rav

Comment: @sam RT full shittah also includes an extra vav in the fourth parsha.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I guess my question was motivated by the fact that I have asked this question of several Rabanim and have been told "no." But upon reading the history of the mahloqeth, I see that RT was the dominant shitta. So, I wondered if anyone here on Mi Yodeya might have some insight. My apologies for being unclear. I am not sure why the questioned is being contested so hard. But I am open to correction regarding it. Kol tuv.

Comment: Why the downvoting?

Answer (score 2):

The Aruch Hashulchan that you refer to, clearly explains that nowadays you cannot wear Rabbeinu Tam Tefilin exclusively.

He admits that in *very early times* there was an argument, but then demonstrates how we Pasken like Rashi.

> ופלא שהרא"ש והטור וכמה מראשונים סבירא להו דרב האי פסק כרבינו תם, והרמב"ם כתב שפתחו תפליו ואינו כן. ובמרדכי וכן בשארי ראשונים כתבו שנפלה הבימה שעל קבר יחזקאל הנביא, ומצאו תפיליו ופתחום, והם כסדר רש"י והרמב"ם. ועל כל פנים נראה שבין קדמוני קדמונים היתה מחלוקת בזה, וכל העולם תפסו כן להלכה. ואף המניחים תפילין דרבינו תם – מברכין רק על תפילין דרש"י ורמב"ם ומתפללים בהם, כאילו בת קול יצא דכן הלכה

He then writes in detail why this is so - quoting from the Zohar.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is relevant. Is there some assumption that everyone forever on must paskin like this Aruch HaShulchan?

Comment: @DoubleAA, the question was based on "historical fact" using this Aruch Hashulchan as the source - I was trying to show that even as per this source the question isn't really valid.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What do you mean "even"? The question is valid even though the Aruch haShulchan paskins a given way, unless you think no one can ever paskin against this Aruch haShulchan (which seems highly questionable).

Comment: @DoubleAA, let me reword myself: Once the Shulchan Aruch decides the Halocho is one way - and nobody "major" subsequently argues, how could we Pasken otherwise? Admittedly, pre-Shulchan Aruch poskim argued, but the Aruch Hashulchan explain why it's no longer relevant.

Comment: I still don't understand your last sentence. The Aruch haShulchan never explained "why it's no longer relevant". He just explained why he doesn't paskin that way. Do you think anyone in 1750's Vilna knew that they were about to have a rabbi who would revolutionize Ashkenazi psak? Of course not. I'm not going to go paskin like Rabbenu Tam here, and forgive me for doubting you to be on that level either, but that in no way makes it impossible. I'm not saying it's probable or even at all likely, only possible, and you have done _absolutely nothing_ in this answer to show otherwise.