# Tefilin Rabbeinu Tam why don't we all do it?

Tags: tefilin

Why is Tefilin not a safek doraisa to require us to put on both rashi and rabbeinu Tam do to safek? Why aren't people machmir?

Comment: this answer, if sourced, would be on point http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/59774/1362 and this answer (second paragraph) also seems relevant http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43697/1362

Comment: Why would you think every machloket is a safek??? There are literally thousands of counterexamples to that.